# What are the good books available on all the Four Vedas in English

Tags: vedas, book-recommendation

Can anyone please suggest me some good books on all the four Vedas in English. Books can be either in Hardcover or in Paperback but not ebook. If anyone has good sources or knowledge regarding this please suggest me the books.

Comment: I went to the link that you provided, there are only online scriptures to read only. I asked for books in Hardcover of Paperback format. Thanks Though @SreeCharan

Answer (score 3):

1. Sama Veda, S.V Ganapathy -> Nice introduction to Sama veda
2. Secrets of Rig veda, R.L. Kashyap -> Nice introduction to Rig veda
3. The Vedas, Sri Chandrasekharendra Saraswati -> Good introductory book by a Sannyasin
4. Brahma Sutras, according to Sankara, Swami Vireshwaranandha, not really vedas but on Upanishad commentaries by Sankaracharya. Quotes vedic hymns as well.

BTW, Samaveda = selected 1000 Riks of Rigveda in musical intonation, so the translations are same

5. The Eight Upanishads Vol 1 & 2 with Sankaracharya commentaries by Swami Gambiranandha( Vedanta part) is also good.
6. Several good Upanishad books,
   Brihadaranyaka Upanishad by Ramakrishna Math is good.
   Maitranya Upanishad, by Edward Byles Cowell is good
   Chandogya Upanishad, by Swami Gambiranandha is good

Translations :

several books by R.T.L Griffith is ok.
Samaveda Samhitha, Ravi Prakash Arya is ok.

I haven't seen Atharva Veda specific books that are good, except Translated ones.

Comment: Sir can the first 2 books be read online for free?

Comment: I don’t think there is online versions of those

Answer (score 2):

Before studying the Vedas, I would recommend you to be perfect in the knowledge of Vedanta. Then you will understand the terms in Vedas easily. You can refer here :[1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44182/19211)

After that you can start with books like Spiritual Heritage of India [2](https://estudantedavedanta.net/spiritual_heritage_india.pdf) or Indian Philosophy a Critical Review [3](https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey) .

I Suggested these books only to have a good introduction about Various schools before starting Vedas. These books are optional but recommended. They are in EBOOK but can be obtained in Paperback but I don't suggest buying these small books.

For Vedas, Start with Aurobindo's book on secret of Vedas [4](http://%5Chttps://www.amazon.in/Secret-Veda-Guidance-Sri-Aurobindo/dp/0914955195/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=)
Sayanacharya is known as one of best commentators on Vedas. HH Wilson has explained his commentary in English briefly .You can buy it here [5](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/four-vedas-rgveda-samaveda-yajurveda-atharvaveda-set-of-9-volumes-sanskrit-text-with-english-translation-NAF115/). I have heard he translated Rig and Atharva Veda Bhasya but I am not sure whether he translated Yajur and Sama Veda Bhasya's. But he translated Samhita and wrote some introduction essays.Sayaancharya's introductary essays on Rig Veda can be purchased here [6](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/sayana-s-preface-to-rgvedabhasya-old-and-rare-book-NAK107/). Another book based on Handbook on Rig Veda(Based on Sayana Bhasya) is available here[7](https://archive.org/details/handbooktostudyo01peteuoft/page/n3/mode/2up).There's another book called Vedic Experience which explains Vedic Poetry in brief and can be purchased here [8](https://www.amazon.in/Vedic-Experience-Mantramanjari-Contemporary-Celebration/dp/8120812808). There are some more small books like Anthology of Vedic Hymms [9](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/anthology-of-vedic-hymns-collection-of-hymns-from-four-vedas-NAJ370/) and Glimpse of 4 Vedas [10](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/glimpses-of-four-vedas-NAR152/). I suggested EBooks for Vedanta Introduction and Paperbacks for Vedas. You need not buy all books. Even for Vedas you have Ebooks online. I didn't give links because you didn't want it. You don't have to buy all these books but think,reason and find out what's good for you and think twice before making any purchasal.

HH Wilson believed that Sayana understood the Vedas far better than any outsider could. He therefore took Sayana as his authority for the meaning of the Vedic words and verses, and closely followed Sayana’s commentary throughout his translation. Griffith tried to strike a balance between Sayana’s interpretations and the interpretations of the German scholars who rejected Sayana, such as Rudolph Roth. His translation is in English verse, which means that he had to adapt the meaning he understood to fit the required number of English syllables.
Satya Prakash and Vidyalankar followed the Arya Samaj line of thought, which rejected Sayana altogether. However, as comparison will show, they adopted much of Wilson’s translation, and thereby brought in quite a bit of Sayana’s interpretation, perhaps unwittingly to themselves. Kashyap followed the Sri Aurobindo line of thought, which also rejected Sayana. His translation includes some of Sri Aurobindo’s psychological interpretations of the Vedas, meanings which were also elaborated by Kapali Sastry in his unfinished Sanskrit commentary. Gautam and his team of co-translators tried to jointly ascertain the meaning of the Vedic verses, and when they reached unanimity on this they attempted to put this meaning into modern English. This translation differs quite a bit from the other English translations. Tulsi Ram’s translation is described in the online listings as following the Arya Samaj line of thought. Jamison and Brereton’s translation is subtitled “The Earliest Religious Poetry of India,” which shows their approach. It draws upon the advances in scholarship over the last century, and will replace Karl Geldner’s German translation as the standard of reference for most Western scholars.

I suggest you to only buy Vedic Commentaries by Sayanacharya because he alone has understood and realized Vedas most perfectly and majority ancient and traditional Scholars accepts his Bhasya as authority. Majority translators have used his Bhasya only to understand Vedas. Don't hesitate to write to me!

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.