# Any Books to understand philosophy of Vedas?

Tags: vedas, book-recommendation

Are there any books to understand Philosophy of Vedic Samhitas? We have many introduction books for Vedanta but not Vedas. Any suggestions??

Comment: Sama Veda by S.V Ganapathy, Secrets of Rig Veda Max Mueller translations

Comment: Please refer to https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/what-are-the-good-books-available-on-all-the-four-vedas-in-english/44171#44171

Comment: :) Is your end goal understanding the Vedic philosophy OR experiencing it?

Please note that experiencing it first hand is much easier than understanding the entire philosophy. If the experience is deep, the understanding can come in a flash!

Answer (score 1):

https://archive.org/details/the-secret-of-the-veda-sri-aurobindo/mode/2up This may help . This book is written by Sri Aurobindo and titled "The Secret of the Veda" . However if you want translation of samhitas , I must warn majority of verses have deep meanings and are not to be understood literally . https://archive.org/search.php?query=dr+tulsi+ram .Here you will find commentary/interpretation of each verse of all 4 vedas . Of course it is not perfect( Dr. Tulsi Ram has excluded Dasrajna war from Rig veda) but still very much good .

Answer (score 0):

There are a huge number of books. However, I would recommend the books by R. L. Kashyap or Kapali Sastri, who was a great scholar, who studied under Ramana Maharshi, Aurobindo and Kavya Kanta Ganapati Muni. [They have a trust](http://vedah.com/product-category/text-in-devanagari-translation-and-notes/) that sells these books. They have a complete 22 volume set that covers all four vedas, including sanskrit, transliteration, translation and interpretation but you can buy each samhita separately also.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey and http://consciouslivingfoundation.org/ebooks/13/CLF-HistoryOfIndianPhilosophy.pdf and also https://www.mlbd.in/

Comment: Hello sir can you please answer my question : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44919/19211