# Is Consiouness Eternal? Does it remain even after death (When we don't have a body?) If yes how can it be known?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, upanishads

Yajnavalkya says in Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 2.4.12 " The self comes out as a separate entity from these elements, and this separateness is destroyed with them. **After attaining this oneness it has no more consciousness** "

But Nirvana Shatkam says Consciousness is Eternal (Indirectly) and other Mahavakyas like Aitareya Upanishad 3.3 say Brahman is Consciousness. Is there a contradiction or fault in my understanding? Can anyone explain in detail?

Note : This question is not the duplicate of [How can Brahman/consciousness be all pervading including living and non living things?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44919/19211)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is consciousness temporary? How can Brahman exist eternally?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45066/is-consciousness-temporary-how-can-brahman-exist-eternally)

Comment: You still have the subtle body after death. That goes with you to the various lokas. Obviously consciousness persists after death, that is the general Astika view. Charvakas etc don't believe consciousness survives death.

Comment: Basically he is talking about Atman or limited consciousness to be destroyed.One Brahman is actually everything 'Sarvam Khalvidam Brahman',hence Yagyavalkya said "As a lump of salt dropped into water dissolves with (its component) water, and no one is able to pick it up, but whencesoever one takes it,it tastes salt, even so, my dear, this great, endless, infinite Reality is but Pure Intelligence." So its non-dual state of Nirvana or Kaivalya or Purusha, no one can define that state with Prakriti and its finite divisions of mind, intellect, words etc., its https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadasiva

Comment: you are confusing the individual waking state consciousness with the Absolute Super-Consciousness.

Comment: Thankyou @Ikshvaku Sir

Comment: @ManuKumar Sir what happens after we leave our body? Formless state how can we have consiouness?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Sir how can Impersonal Super Consiouness exist? For Consiouness to exist we need a form right ?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru you can't comprehend God or spirituality with intellect or reading books or on internet on own, else it will only lead to your life's time waste, some Guru guidance is needed. Consciousness is Atman, after death a body gets new body based on Karmas and desires, end of sensory desires alone can lead to formless state, hence the need of Vedas with Karma Kanda for Dharma, Artha, Kama and Gyana Kand for Moksha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing between particular consciousness and the all-pervading consciousness of Brahman. The particular consciousness is responsible for the thought I am that, I am Setu, I am engineer etc. This will not survive death while the all-pervading consciousness is independent of time and body.

Shankara explains in his bhashya of this verse in detail. See the last paragraph

> Brahman in association with avidya appears as the elements, which are
> transformed into the body, organs, and sense objects, consisting of
> name and form. They are like foam and bubbles on the limpid water of
> the Supreme Self. With the aid of these elements the self comes out
> like a lump of salt. As from water, reflections of the sun, moon, and
> so on arise, or from the proximity of a red cotton pad etc., a
> transparent crystal turns red etc., so from the limiting adjuncts of
> the elements, transformed into body and organs and sense-objects, the
> self comes out clearly as an individualized entity. Through the
> instruction of the scriptures and the teacher, these elements, which
> are the cause of individualization, merge in Brahman, as rivers merge
> in the ocean. [Technically, this should read as appears to emerge and appears to merge etc.]
>
> DESTROYED: When the elements are destroyed, this individualized
> existence is also destroyed with them. As the reflections of the sun,
> moon, etc. and the colour of the crystal vanish when their causes the
> water, the red cotton pad, etc. are removed, and only the sun, moon,
> etc. remain as they are, so the endless, infinite, and limpid Pure
> Intelligence alone remains.
>
> **No MORE CONSCIOUSNESS**: That is to say, no more **particular
> consciousness**. "No more is there such a thought as: I, So-and-so, am
> the son of So and so; this is my land and wealth; I am happy or
> miserable. For such **particular consciousness** is due to ignorance, and
> since ignorance is absolutely destroyed by the realization of Brahman,
> how can the knower of Brahman, who is established in his nature of
> Pure Intelligence, **possibly have any particular consciousness**?

Comment: Sir I am not getting this again and again, after we get Moksha(Leave body) what is that we experience ? Nothing right?

Comment: One who has realised Brahman is constantly in peace and bliss because the nature of Brahman is bliss. Moksha is realising that you are Brahman.

Comment: Sir that Bliss wont be there if we leave our body na so how is bliss eternal

Comment: Please read mandukya karika. The consciousness I am talking about is beyond waking, dream and deep sleep. You are confusing body consciousness with eternal consciousness.

Comment: Sir yes I am aware of these 3 types. Even CHandogya mentions 3 states of consiouness and Indra learns from PRajapti to think beyond these 3 states. What happens after you leave this body?When theres nothing existing (without body) how can you say I am consiounes of this or that etc

Comment: You quoted Mandukya verse 7 and few Ramana Maharshi quotes but it is really not getting me...this is why I am asking qn in different ways...