# What are the important texts/scriptures of VisistAdvaita Vedanta?

Tags: scripture, vedanta, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita

The central texts common to the various Vedanta schools are Upanishads, Brahma Sutras and Bhagavad Gita collectively referred to as [Prasthanatrayi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasthanatrayi)<sup>1</sup>. Another central text of VisistAdvaita is [Nathamuni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathamuni)'s anthology of the divine poetry of the [Azhwars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvars), the poet-saints of Vishnu, called [Naalayira Divya Prabhandham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naalayira_Divya_Prabhandham) also referred to as the Dravida Vedas (based on their effulgent exemplification of Bhakti).

Apart from these, which scriptures/texts are considered important in the VisistAdvaita Canon of Literature? Please give a brief overview of why each of the texts you mention are considered important acc. to VisistAdvaita Siddhanta (for instance due to its historical importance and/or acute philosophical insights and/or elegant exposition, etc,.)

<sub>1. credit where it's due - this question is inspired by a similar question on Advaita Vedanta which you can read [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12060/which-are-the-principle-texts-scriptures-of-advaita-vedanta)</sub>

Comment: I was gonna ask this question lol

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury you can always answer!

Comment: I would also suggest Yatindaramatadipika a philosophical work dealing with Vishistadviata.

Answer (score 7):

Actually Ramanujacharya has written three commentaries on Brahma Sutra:

- Sri Bhashhya (श्री भाष्य​)
- Veanta Sara (वेदान्त​ सार​)
- Vedanta Dipa (वेदान्त​ दीप​)

Apart from Sri Bhashya, One of the important work is **Vedartha Samgraha (वेदार्थ​ संग्रह​)**.

> श्रीभाष्यकृद-उपन्यस्तो यः श्रीशैलपतेः पुरः ।
>   **वेदार्थसङ्ग्रह**स्यास्य कुर्मः तात्पर्यदीपिकाम् ॥

Vedartha Sangraha contains all the philosophical tents preached in the Upanishads. According to Ramanujacharya, all the texts needs to be interpreted properly to seek the correct truth since he was disagree with some aspects of Advaita. That's why in order to know and understand the true meanings of Upanishads, to overcome the difficulty in the interpretation, he has written a work called Vedartha Sangraha. It embodies a comprehensive and synoptic interpretation of the deepest insights of the Upanishads and also debates with previous works on Vedanta.

You can read the Overview of Vedartha Sangraha at [Ramanuja.org](http://ramanuja.org/sri/Web/VedarthasangrahaOverview).

> Prof. M. Hiriyanna describes it as
>  
>   “an independent treatise explaining in a masterly way his philosophic position, and pointing out the basis for it in the Upanishads.”

You can get Vedartha Sangra Sanskrit with English translation at [here](http://estudantedavedanta.net/Vedartha-Sangraha.pdf) and Sanskrit with Hindi translation at [here](https://archive.org/details/VedarthaSangrahaOfRamaujaNeelMeghacharya).

---

After Sri Ramanujacharya, the most popular Accharya in Vishishtadvaita tradition is Vedanta Desika who has given clear, complete and comprehensive exposition of Vishishtadvaitic thoughts and Sri Vaishnava tradition in the (Tamil) work **Rahasyatraya Sara (रहस्यत्रय सार​)**.

...

Comment: After Ramanujacharya, there are many other famous acharyas. Vedanta Desikan is one of them. He is not the only one famous after Ramanujacharya. Rahasya Traya sara is not a tamil work. It is written in Mani Pravalam style, a mix of Tamil and Sankrit. It is more of a Sri Vaishnava work which talks more about surrender than the philosophical Vishishtadvaita.