# What ancient texts talk about tantra?

Tags: scripture, tantra

I want to know about tantra, but I don't know which books to go to. Can anyone tell me which books should I refer to for learning more about tantra?

Comment: Same question here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29538/how-can-i-start-tantra-sadhna-which-all-are-the-scriptures-i-need-to-study-to-h/29545#29545

Comment: @Rickross there are so many tantras and related books published in bengali.But it seems many are not avaialble in English like Upendrakumar's and Nigamananda's books--isnt it?

Comment: Yes probably not available in English or in other languages @Pratimaputra