# Does anyone know if there is an English translation of Rudrayamala Tantram?

Tags: scripture, translation-request, tantra

Is there an English translation of Rudrayamala Tantra available?

Please provide the link for the same.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is no complete English Translation of the *Rudra-Yamala* scripture because the original manuscripts of the Original *Rudra-Yamala* are lost, unfortunately.

This is what [Hindupedia-site says](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Tantra/Rudrayamala.html)-

> **The Rudrayamala is used as a source by many other agamas but the original appears to be lost.** Strictly speaking, a Yamala is a
> different class of text, and supposed to pre-date the tantras.
> **However, manuscripts of the Yamala seem to be lost, except as quotations in later works.**

They are providing a chapter-wise summarized analysis of a published work, a tantra with the same name, but they maintain that the Original *Rudra-Yamala* is a lost text now.

> **This analysis of the contents is of a tantra given the same name, but
> almost certainly, from internal evidence, not the original text.**
> Although its provenance is unknown, it nevertheless contains a great
> deal of interesting information and focuses in great detail on the
> identity of the goddess with Kundalini. *Published in a Sanskrit
> edition by the Vacasampati Press, Calcutta, this work is divided into
> 66 chapters (patala) of different lengths and written in a simple
> manner.*_ Here is a digest of its contents (under construction).

Comment: In fact, many tantras seem to be lost, and please share links on our site if any are available. @Ricross mentioned that [only a few are available](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29545/661), especially in English.