# Advaita vedanta texts recommendations

Tags: vedanta, advaita, translation-request, book-recommendation

Can you please recommend some high quality texts on pure Advaita philosophy from an academic standpoint which are complete and exhaustive by themselves?

Academic works like that of P. S. Roodurmum (Bhamati-Vivarana schools) or translation of some classical texts like Bhamati by S. S. Shastri, Bhasya (Swami Gambhirananda) would be ideal.

It would be nice if you could also recommend some of the most popular translations of all the major advaitic texts both intermediate and advanced.

Comment: [Related not duplicate] [Which are the principle texts/scriptures of Advaita Vedanta?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12060/3500)

Comment: Sharma has 2 books which are excellent from a Academic standpoint. One on line - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey . The other is an expansion of parts of this book, its called 'The Advaita Tradition in Indian Philosophy: A Study of Advaita in Buddhism, Vedanta and Kashmira Shaivism'. Asking for 'best translations' is asking for opinions and not allowed per forum rules.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Can you write a brief answer ,as you are very well aware of the good books related to the topic.