# Advaita Epistemology

Tags: vedanta, advaita

Can someone please recommend books on advaita epistemology. Suggestion of both classical and academic works would be equally helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Which are the principal texts of Advaita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12060/277)

Comment: Who am I? by Raman Maharshi, Ashtavakra Geeta and Upanishads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advaita vedanta texts recommendations](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35302/5212)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to read Vedanta Paribhasha by Dharmaraja Adhvarindra, translated into English by Swami Madhvananda. You can read it online [here](http://estudantedavedanta.net/Vedanta%20Paribhasa%20of%20Dharmaraja%20Adhvarindra%20-%20Swami%20Madhavananda%20[Sanskrit-English].pdf).