# Would Narayana listen if someone were to chant his name without going to a temple?

Tags: vishnu, gods, vaishnavism, dharma, advaita

This probably sounds like a dumb question, but I am unable to visit any temples as I don't live in India. That being said, any effort is probably better than none at all. Would Nama jap of Narayana (Vishnu) be helpful like that, even if I don't visit his temple?

Comment: It's more like an opinion based questions. Maybe you can get some relevant verses. Just for example, Brahman manifests as per the worshippers tutelage, when the devotee is pure and devoted. Ex:- Markandeya saved by Shiva. & Gajendra, Prahlad, Dhruv, etc,. by Vishnu, et al. Ultimately, one has to realize the Supreme as the inner light of all mobile and immobile consciousness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, even if you don't chant with devotion, Lord will listen to you because he is all pervading and gives knowledge to you in form of Paramatma residing in your heart.

> When people properly glorify the Supreme Personality of Godhead or
> simply hear about His power, the Lord personally enters their hearts
> and cleanses away every trace of misfortune, just as the sun removes
> the darkness or as a powerful wind drives away the clouds.(Srimad
> Bhagavata 12.12.48)
>
> To those who are constantly devoted to serving Me with love, I give
> the understanding by which they can come to Me. To show them special
> mercy, I, dwelling in their hearts, destroy with the shining lamp of
> knowledge the darkness born of ignorance.(Gita 10.11-12)
>
> One who chants the holy name of the Lord is immediately freed from the
> reactions of unlimited sins, even if he chants indirectly [to indicate
> something else], jokingly, for musical entertainment, or even
> neglectfully. This is accepted by all the learned scholars of the
> scriptures.(Srimad Bhagavata 6.2.14)

Comment: Good answer. First sentence should read, "even if you don't chant with devotion.." Am I correct? Also, temple is a new concept. An elderly person may not be able to go to temple or public places of worship.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Yes sir that's what I wrote! Sir would love to read your answer on https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12060/19211 
Do see my answer also!

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru If I simply chant or say "Narayana, Narayana, Narayana....", right?

Comment: Yes! @LearningHindu ! Any name of Lord ! All names are equally auspecious!

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru Thank you sir. Actually, I have not read many of the books you have listed. I have read only the works of Shankaracharya and Madhusudhana Saraswati and Ramana Maharshi. See https://adishankaracharya.net/links. I like Amrut's web site you mention. Another site is by Dennis Waite. See http://www.advaita.org.uk/library/library.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful links @GIRIBLR Sir ! THe sites are so wonderful! Could you please tell works of Madhusudhana Saraswathi Ji and Ramana Maharshi works to be studied? I do have Madhusuhan Ji's Gita Bhasya...

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru Advaita Siddhi and Siddhanta Bindu by Madhusudhana Saraswathi are available in adishankaracharya.net/links. Bhagavan books are available in https://archive.org/details/ramanamaharishiebooks/Ramana%20Maharishi%20eBooks/Collected_works

Comment: Thanks a lot @GIRIBLR sir!

Comment: @GIRIBLR Sir I want to share few more links though your website covers everything
http://absoluteadvaitavedanta.blogspot.com/2018/12/hinduism-scriptures.html
https://estudantedavedanta.net/veliingles.html
Do kindly share Advaitha Vedanta sites like the above Adishankaracharya.net....It was soo wonderful!!!!!

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru Yes, your links are great. But I like works by Adi Shankara because he wrote for all levels. For example, his work, Bala-bodha-sangraha is meant for eight year old asking questions on vedanta. His bhashya are meant for people at the highest level. Thus Shankara itself covers all levels of advaita. But he does not refute other schools like dvaita because they came later. Thus Madhusudhana Sarasvati is required reading because he refutes all other philosophies.

Comment: Very true sir! Sir the website you gave covers almost all literature on Advaitha na??Adishankaracharya.net .. ?Could you suggest such websites?? Sir few books mentioned in it are deleted by archieve sadly :(

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Because I am a novice, I am unable to visualize Narayana when I say "Narayana". I don't have that much time either to sit quietly and meditate upon Narayana as I am quite busy nowadays. I hope Prabhu would still be able to hear me anyway!

Comment: See the above verse. Even if you chant jokingly also or to mean something different, he accepts it :) So don't worry @LearningHindu